# Functor type variables for Flip data type

Tags: haskell, arguments, functor, newtype

I have following type definition:

```
newtype Flip f a b = 
  Flip (f b a) deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Does the `Flip` data constructor has one or three arguments?

Consinder following implementation:

```
data K a b = K a

newtype Flip f a b = 
  Flip (f b a) deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor (Flip K a) where
  fmap f (Flip (K b)) = Flip (K (f b))
```

What is the type of `(Flip K a)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Flip` data constructor has **one argument**. That argument has type `f b a`.

That thus means that `f` itself is a higher order type argument with type `f :: * -> * -> *`. A more rigorous `newtype` statement would be:

```
newtype Flip (f :: * -> * -> *) a b = Flip (f b a)
```

You can thus for instance instantiate a `Flip Either Int Bool`, since `Either` is a type that requires two additional type parameters, and then construct a `Flip (Right 1) :: Flip Either Int Bool`.

> What is the type of `(Flip K a)`?

`Flip K a` is not a fully applied type. In *pseudo-code*, it has type `b -> Flip K a b`. Once the `b` has been resolved (`Functor` works with higher order types), we know that the only argument of `Flip` will have a `K b` constructor. So for instance `Flip (K 1)` is a `Flip K a Int` type.

Comment: Is "fully grounded" a technical term? I've only hear fully applied. Just curious...

Comment: @Alec: no, that was a mistake (too much into Prolog :))

Comment: How does the compiler know, that the type signature of Flip is `(* -> * -> *) -> * -> * -> *` not `* -> * -> * -> *`?

Comment: Because the first one (between the brackets), is the `f` type parameter. It is the same with parameters of functions (only one meta level higher).

Comment: So the compiler analyse the data constructor also? So when I define without parentheses `Prelude> data Flip f b c = Flip f b c` then it becomes to `Flip :: * -> * -> * -> *`.

Answer (score 7):

The future is now, when you (use ghc 8 and) switch on a flag or two

```
Prelude> :set -XPolyKinds -XFlexibleInstances
```

Let us declare

```
Prelude> newtype Flip f a b = MkFlip (f b a)
```

and then enquire

```
Prelude> :kind Flip
Flip :: (k1 -> k -> *) -> k -> k1 -> *

Prelude> :type MkFlip
MkFlip
  :: forall k k1 (b :: k) (f :: k -> k1 -> *) (a :: k1).
     f b a -> Flip f a b
```

The *type* constructor `Flip` takes two implicit arguments, being `k` and `k1`, and three explicit arguments, being a binary function producing a type, then its two arguments in reverse order. The arguments to this function are of unconstrained type (old people can say "kind" if they like), but it certainly returns a type (in the strict sense of "thing in `*`", rather than the uselessly vague sense of "any old rubbish right of `::`") because it is certainly used as a type in the declaration of `MkFlip`.

The *data* constructor, `MkFlip`, takes *five* implicit arguments (exactly the arguments of `Flip`) and one explicit argument, being some data in `f b a`.

What's going on is Hindley-Milner type inference one level up. Constraints are collected (e.g., `f b a` must inhabit `*` because a constructor argument must inhabit `f b a`) but otherwise a most general type is delivered: `a` and `b` could be anything, so their types are generalised as `k1` and `k`.

Let's play the same game with the constant type constructor:

```
Prelude> newtype K a b = MkK a

Prelude> :kind K
K :: * -> k -> *

Prelude> :type MkK
MkK :: forall k (b :: k) a. a -> K a b
```

We see that `a :: *` but `b` can be any old rubbish (and for that matter, `k :: *`, as these days, `* :: *`). Clearly, `a` is actually used as the type of a thing, but `b` is not used at all, hence unconstrained.

We may then declare

```
Prelude> instance Functor (Flip K b) where fmap f (MkFlip (MkK a)) = MkFlip (MkK (f a))
```

and ask

```
Prelude> :info Flip
...
instance [safe] forall k (b :: k). Functor (Flip K b)
```

which tells us that the unused `b` can still be any old rubbish. Because we had

```
K    ::   * -> k -> *
Flip :: (k1 -> k -> *) -> k -> k1 -> *
```

we can unify `k1 = *` and get

```
Flip K :: k -> * -> *
```

and so

```
Flip K b :: * -> *
```

for any old `b`. A `Functor` instance is thus plausible, and indeed deliverable, with the function acting on the packed up `a` element, corresponding to the argument of `Flip K b` which becomes the *first* argument of `K`, hence the type of the stored element.

Unification-based type inference is alive and (fairly) well, right of `::`.

Comment: Could you please explain `forall k k1 (b :: k) (f :: k -> k1 -> *) (a :: k1)`, how to read it? Or what does it mean.

Comment: I can try. Constructors like `MkFlip` take some *invisible* arguments that live in the world of types, as well as their *visible* arguments that live in the world of values. (There used to be a good reason why types were invisible and values were visibile, but it isn't good any more and we're stuck with it.) The big long `forall ...` is telling you about the invisible stuff, explaining exactly how polymorphic `MkFlip` is. It's very polymorphic. It says `f` is any two-parameter type former; `k` and `k1` are the (arbitrary) types of its parameters, but `b` fits with `k` and `a` fits with `k1`.